# C# find reference of a class in a directory of .cs files

Tags: c#, reflection, unity-game-engine, reference

I want to create a method that simulates the VS "Find All References" function.

I want to use this method in Unity3D to basically find any script that isn't being referenced in any other script.

I have a folder with .cs files, and the name of those files correspond to the C# class that's inside the file.

Then for each class(file) I want to search if there's a reference of it on the rest of the files.

Is there a straightforward way of doing this? Or should I just try to parse the files?

Edit: The code is also compiled.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not compiled, you can't use reflection. Your only choice is to actually parse the whole code, which is not that simple. You can always use ready-made parts, like Roslyn, but it will still take some work to get it done.

If you were to inspect compiled code, then you could read from the metadata all classes used and methods called and this would be a lot simpler.

Comment: The code is compiled as well, sorry for not mentioning that.